# Was CTAN the first software repository?

Tags: tex-history

I am currently preparing a course about creating Python packages and I want to start with a history of key developments in software distribution. One corner stone are software repositories. PyPI (Python) was created in 2000 and inspired by CPAN. CPAN (Perl) was created in 1993 and is inspired by CTAN. CTAN was created in 1992.

I can't find any earlier software repository. Was CTAN actually something unique which was not available in other programming languages? Or was CTAN inspired by other projects?

Comment: You might want to tighten up your requirements here; CTAN was based on the Aston archive, which was one of many tape-based systems for archiving 'stuff' ...

Comment: there were many software repositories ftp archives etc, but ctan was (possibly) the first that aimed to be (a) globally coordinated and (b) _Comprehensive_ for a particular software system.

Comment: @JosephWright not only tape, JANET was active even if we didn't have the internet:-)

Comment: The obvious reference is http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb14-3/tb40green.pdf

Comment: @egreg a list of very honourable people in the footnote on page 1.

Comment: @egreg Awesome, I was looking for something like that :-) I didn't completely read it by now, but it looks as if people were sharing stuff via ftp before? - anyway, I think this link + Davids comment is already an acceptable answer for me :-)

Comment: I love you guys  - It's always a nice experience to ask questions here :-)

Comment: @MartinThoma Or via [BITNET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BITNET).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The early Linux distributions had a sort of package repositories (e.g. Slackware). Earlier you could get sources for Linux-hacked stuff on some places (forget details, that was 1992 or so for me).

Earliest repositories (source) were e.g. the GNU mirrors (starting around 1985 or so), public FTP (and gopher) sites were plenty by 1990 (and probably much, much older). Binary packages were not popular, due to wild differences in architecture/operating system/setup common in the '80s. A common way to share sources (for non-Internet connected sites in the '80s) were Usenet groups like comp.sources.unix (got my first version of Perl as thirty-something posts you had to unpack an stitch together just right, configure by futzing in Makefile macros and then --hopefully-- build.

First mention of software sharing I've seen documented was the custom of dropping off tapes with interesting stuff at DECUS (DEC User group) conferences, and pick them up with a compilation of everything contributed at the end. I believe IBM users had something similar going too. This was in the '70s  or even earlier (sorry, away on vacation, no access to my computer now).

Answer (score 13):

CTAN was preceded by the Aston Archive, as reported in several TUGboat articles:

- "[A UK-Based TeX Mail Archive Server](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-3/tb22site.pdf)",
  by Peter Abbott, November 1988
- "[UKTeX and the Aston Archive](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23site.pdf)",
  by Peter Abbott, April 1989
- "[UKTeX and the Aston Archive](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-2/tb24resources.pdf)",
  by Peter Abbott, July 1989
- "[The UKTeX Archive at the University of Aston](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-4/tb26abbott.pdf)",
  by Peter Abbott, November 1989

However, as noted in the answer by @vonbrand, DECUS
was almost certainly earlier in having a formal
software distribution mechanism, on tape.  TeX was
part of this collection, as reported in TUGboat:

- "[The DECUS TeX Collection](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-2/tb24resources.pdf)".
  by M. Edward Nieland, November 1989, pp.195-196

Several followup reports appear in later TUGboat issues.

TeX was an active topic at DECUS meetings; this is the earliest report:

- "[TeX at the 1981 Spring DECUS U. S. symposium](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb02-2/tb03site.pdf)",
  by Patrick Milligan, July 1981, p.29

I can't say whether the UKTeX archive was inspired
by other software projects, but it was clearly something
that was needed, and initiated to meet that need.